# Why am I unable to select/click a bare text link with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium web driver and Selenium IDE plugin for Firefox.

All I'm trying to do is click "United States" on the language page.

http://www.nike.com/language_tunnel

I am trying this (straight from the IDE recorder):

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]").click()
driver.find_element_by_link_text("United States").click()
```

Note that the first step works, it clicks on "AMERICAS", but the last step to click on "United States" errors out when I run it in Python with:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"United States"}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there another way to select this link since find by link text apparently won't work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things I've done to make it work:

- changed the locator to a `li.US a` CSS selector
- added a wait to wait for the visibility of the "US" link

The Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://www.nike.com/language_tunnel")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[2]").click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.US a"))).click()
```